# Matching Prefix or _Prefix in the given millions of Data

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have got a problem in which there is list cotaning name and score.I've to convert it into Serializable data and then search for a given query "s" such that I've to return top scores whose name contains "s" or "_s" in JAVA.

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: I've tried Maps but that's not performance friendly.

Comment: it is not clear how did you try Maps... I would recommend to retrieve names that contain "s" or "_s" first. And then sort out result. Please provide [mcve] for further help

Comment: I was doing the same thing which you're suggesting but if there are millions of data in that case this won't be a feasible solution.